# Typesafe implementation of Firebase Firestore's `where`

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, code-generation

I'm writing a type safe builder package to wrap Firestore primitives called [Fireproof](https://github.com/Nolence/fireproof). I'm currently working on wrapping a [Query.where](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/2ca476431a2a8ed262080bf7282915a3b893f429/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query.dart#L334)  with my own custom `FireQuery.where` that I want to be fully typesafe. The Firestore `where` has a function declaration of

```dart
Query where(
    dynamic field, {
    dynamic isEqualTo,
    dynamic isNotEqualTo,
    dynamic isLessThan,
    dynamic isLessThanOrEqualTo,
    dynamic isGreaterThan,
    dynamic isGreaterThanOrEqualTo,
    dynamic arrayContains,
    List<dynamic>? arrayContainsAny,
    List<dynamic>? whereIn,
    List<dynamic>? whereNotIn,
    bool? isNull,
  }) {/*...*/}
```

but as I'm generating code around one specific model or document, I know all the possible fields and their types so I don't want anything to be dynamic. However, I can't think of a way to take advantage of that or what the function call might look like.

Here's an example considering I have a user document

```dart
class UserDoc {
  final int age;

  final String city;

  UserDoc(this.age, this.city);
}
```

and a UserQuery:

```dart
/// Generated Code
class UserQuery implements FireQuery {
  // ...

  UserQuery where(
    // I know the only fields possible are age and city therefore
    // I want the comparators to be typed to whatever is the selected field.
    //
    // E.g. If the user somehow selects age, isEqualTo should be isEqualTo<String>
  ) {
    // TODO
  }
}
```

Any ideas how this could be done?

## EDIT

I deprecated the package in favor of Firestore's native `withConverters` and came to the same conclusion that, without partial classes or a large breaking change to the api this wouldn't be possible

Answer (score 0):

You first link isn't working. Did you delete the project?

The dynamic part of the code you are referencing to it's there to adapt to any query you want to do. So if the user selects age you just need the following:

```dart
CollectionReference colref = Firestore.instance
    .collection("usersCollection");

Query nameQuery = colref.where('age', isEqualTo: 'TheAgeYouWant');
```

and it will automatically get set to the value of Age. The point of using FlutterFire code is not having to create your own custom query and I don't think it really generates any benefits or advantages.

Comment: Yeah, the package was deprecated in favor of `withConverter`s. The author behind the change agreed that it wouldn't be possible currently to have what I was thinking without some language features currently in the works